# Implementing 'background-size: cover' in Android

Tags: android, css, image

I would like to have the background image to behave the same as the following line behave in CSS:

```
'background-size: cover'
```

Is this the right way to do it:

> If the image is smaller than destination, enlarge to the destination size while keeping, aspect
>   ratio and then crop the image to fit the destination.
>   If the image is larger than destination, crop the image to fit the destination.